# Problem on starting SQL Server “FCB::Open: Operating system error 3”

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have installed SQL SERVER 2005 sp3 and when i try to start it, i get the following error

from sql server ErrorLog：

```
2010-12-12 01:05:54.40 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (Intel X86) 
 Nov 24 2008 13:01:59 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

2010-12-12 01:05:54.40 Server      (c) 2005 Microsoft Corporation.
2010-12-12 01:05:54.40 Server      All rights reserved.
2010-12-12 01:05:54.40 Server      Server process ID is 3028.
2010-12-12 01:05:54.40 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2010-12-12 01:05:54.40 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'F:\sql-log\ERRORLOG'.
2010-12-12 01:05:54.40 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 1576 at 2010-12-12 1:03:14 (local) 2010-12-11 17:03:14 (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2010-12-12 01:05:54.40 Server      Registry startup parameters:

-d C:\master.mdf

-e F:\sql-log\ERRORLOG

 -e F:\sql-log\ERRORLOG

SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

Detected 8 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

Set AWE Enabled to 1 in the configuration parameters to allow use of more memory.

Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
Attempting to initialize Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
Attempting to recover in-doubt distributed transactions involving Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

 Database mirroring has been enabled on this instance of SQL Server.
Starting up database 'master'.

error: 17207，severity: 16，state: 1。

 **FCB::Open: Operating system error 3(file not found.) occurred while creating or opening file ''. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.**

 Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.

**FCB::Open failed: Could not open file  for file number 2.  OS error: 3(file not found.).**

 Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.

**unable to open the physical file ""。Operating system error 3:"3(file not found.)"。**
```

why the file name is empty？

it should be “c:\master.mdf”

Seems to be the same problem. How to change that path to the correct one? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something got changed in the SQL Server configuration. The error log reads

> -d C:\master.mdf
>
> -e F:\sql-log\ERRORLOG
>
> -e F:\sql-log\ERRORLOG

The -l parameter which stands for master database log file is missing. Please launch SQL Server Configuration Manager and change the startup parameters of SQL Server service. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015754) are the steps to troubleshoot this issue.